# My if & elif not working on sockets (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, socketserver, python-sockets

I tried to create a server that receives commands from the client
And to identify which command the client wrote I used if & elif
But when I run the program and write a command from the client, only the first command works (the command on the if) and if I try another command (from elif & else)
The system just doesn't respond (like she's waiting for something)

The Server Code:

```
import socket
import time
import random as rd


soc = socket.socket()
soc.bind(("127.0.0.1", 7777))

soc.listen(5)
(client_socket, address) = soc.accept()

if(client_socket.recv(4) == b"TIME"):
    client_socket.send(time.ctime().encode())

elif(client_socket.recv(4) == b"NAME"):
    client_socket.send(b"My name is Test Server!")

elif(client_socket.recv(4) == b"RAND"):
    client_socket.send(str(rd.randint(1,10)).encode())

elif(client_socket.recv(4) == b"EXIT"):
    client_socket.close()

else:
    client_socket.send(b"I don't know what your command means")


soc.close()
```

The Client Code:

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect(("127.0.0.1", 7777))

client_command_to_the_server = input("""
These are the options you can request from the server:

TIME --> Get the current time

NAME --> Get the sevrer name

RAND --> Get a Random int

EXIT --> Stop the connect with the server


""").encode()

soc.send(client_command_to_the_server)
print(soc.recv(1024))

soc.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(client_socket.recv(4) == b"TIME"):
    client_socket.send(time.ctime().encode())
```

This will check the **first** 4 byte received from the server

```
elif(client_socket.recv(4) == b"NAME"):
    client_socket.send(b"My name is Test Server!")
```

This will check the **next** 4 bytes received from the server.  Contrary to what you assume it will not check the first bytes again since you called `recv` to read more bytes. If there are no more bytes (likely, since the first 4 bytes are already read) it will simply wait. Instead of calling `recv` for each comparison you should call `recv` once and then compare the result against the various strings.

Apart from that: `recv` will only return **up to** the given number of bytes. It might also return less.